# Перенос кода "pointer = nil;" в отдельный метод

Tags: objective-c

У меня возникла необходимость перенести release и обнуление объекта в отдельный метод. Но после вызова этого метода указатель не становится nil. Вот код, описывающий проблему:

```
- (void)releaseAndSetNil:(MyClass *)inP
{
    [inP release];
    inP = nil;
}

- (void)mainFunction
{
    // this code works
    MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [p release];
    p = nil; // (MyClass *) $0 = 0x0000000000000000 <nil>

    // this code does not work
    MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [self releaseAndSetNil:p]; // (MyClass *) $1 = 0x0000000100108340 [no Objective-C description available]
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: +1 за минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему

Comment: @hash3r: (там комментарии закончились) вот видите, ваш пример только подтверждает то, что я говорю. Объект удалён, но `p` не `nil`. Вопрос был не в том, как удалить объект, а о том, как обнулить указатель.

Comment: я так поняла, что self = nil; не работает потому, что в self находится копия адреса и его изменение на p никак не повлияет (p, кстати, тоже копия). (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767916/objective-c-self-nil-doesnt-set-instance-to-null-value)

Comment: @VladD: почему не обнуляется не пойму пока. я думал освобождения достаточно)
@Anastasia: в releaseAndSetNil передается не копия. зайдите дебаггером в эту функцию и убедитесь, что адреса p и self одинаковы

Comment: @hash3r: посмотрите вопрос, он именно про обнуление.

> Но после вызова этого метода указатель не становится nil.

Вы про какую процедуру говорите насчёт "адреса p и self одинаковы"? self ни в одной из процедур, о которых мы говорим, не передаётся в качестве параметра.

Comment: @hash3r: да, p и self хранят одинаковый адрес объекта, но &p и &self - разные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм. В Objective C, как и в чистом C, параметры передаются [*по значению*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892520/passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference-in-objective-c). То есть, в процедуре `releaseAndSetNil` вы обнуляете *копию* вашего `p`.

Передать сам `p` вы не можете, поэтому передавайте его *адрес*. Имея адрес, вы сможете сделать с переменной что угодно.

Чтобы правильно работало, передавайте указатель на указатель:

```
- (void)releaseAndSetNil:(MyClass **)inPP
{
    [*inPP release];
    *inPP = nil;
}
```

(если не наврал с синтаксисом).

Answer (score 2):

> Хм. В Objective C, как и в чистом C,
> параметры передаются по значению

**Вам кот-то сказал не правду.**

// метод класса MyClass

```
 - (void)releaseAndSetNil
    {
        [self release];
        self = nil;
    }

- (void)mainFunction
{

    // this code  works
    MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [p releaseAndSetNil];
}
```

**UPD**
(lldb) p [(int)p retainCount] никогда не покажет Вам нуль, т. к. когда у объекта 0 ссылок на него он вызывает dealloc

**UPD2**
если все еще не верите, вот более убедительные доказательства)
Релиз объекта не обязательно происходит мгновенно. Когда он происходит это уже его детали реализации.

Если запустить такой код

```
MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [p releaseAndSetNil];
    [p retain];
```

то получим 
*** -[MyClass retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
что есть доступ к деаллоцированной памяти. это свидетельствует об релизе объекта р в releaseAndSetNil:

Comment: почему  не получается комментировать чужие записи? кармы не хватае что ли)?

Comment: @hash3r: а чем это противоречит моему утверждению? `self`-то не параметр. И в исходном вопросе надо было убить _другой_ объект, а не самого себя.

Comment: @hash3r: хорошо, не убить, лишь убить свою ссылку. Кстати, а что будет с вашим кодом, если refcount не 0? Не знаю, как в Objective C, а в C++ `self` -- константа, так что я не уверен, скомпилируется ли ваш код.

Comment: @hash3r: а в чем неправда? хочу разобраться.

Comment: @anastasia: StackOverflow [утверждает](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892520/passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference-in-objective-c), что таки параметры передаются по значению.

Comment: @hash3r: можете вывести `p` в конце `mainFunction`?

Comment: (lldb) po p
(MyClass *) $0 = 0x00000001023003a0 <MyClass: 0x1023003a0>
(lldb) p [(int)p retainCount]
(int) $1 = 1

Не зарелизился и не обнулился...

Comment: @VladD 
1) releaseAndSetNil: это в принципе тот же dealloc только вызывается когда хочешь и есть меотдом класса.

<<
 MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [self releaseAndSetNil:p]; 
>> 
тут от контекста зависит. кто здесь self ? зачем ему освобожать какую-то переменную, если она сама может себя освободить своим же методом releaseAndSetNil:

Comment: 2) это plain типы(не ссылки на объект) передаются по значению. NSInteger, BOOL например.
MyClass *p = [[MyClass alloc] init];  --> объекты типа, ссылка на MyClass.
тут получается словесная путаница. передается то "по значению", но значение есть ссылка на объект.

Comment: объект-ссылка реально передается по значению, если передавать его копию.